# Calling ToList() on MongoDB FindAsync() is running slower compared to reading the same JSON from file storage in .NET Core 6

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, .net-6.0

I am storing City-based hotelsearch responses in MongoDB, with around 600 documents, each containing nested lists.

My query is quite straightforward. I am fetching documents based on the requestId, and I have already created an index on requestId. The query looks like {"RequestId" : "1232423"}, and it takes around 130 milliseconds on MongoDB Compass.

However, the below query in .NET 6 takes around 2500-3000 milliseconds:

```
_search2.FindAsync(e => true && e.RequestId == RequestId).Result.ToList();
```

Additionally, if I store the same JSON file in file storage, read, and deserialize it again, it takes around 1000 milliseconds. This was the earlier implementation, but now we have decided to migrate to MongoDB to improve performance.

Below is executionStats of above query

```
{
  explainVersion: '1',
  queryPlanner: {
    namespace: 'test.CitySearch',
    indexFilterSet: false,
    parsedQuery: { RequestId: { '$eq': '1232423' } },
    maxIndexedOrSolutionsReached: false,
    maxIndexedAndSolutionsReached: false,
    maxScansToExplodeReached: false,
    winningPlan: { stage: 'EOF' },
    rejectedPlans: []
  },
  executionStats: {
    executionSuccess: true,
    nReturned: 0,
    executionTimeMillis: 0,
    totalKeysExamined: 0,
    totalDocsExamined: 0,
    executionStages: {
      stage: 'EOF',
      nReturned: 0,
      executionTimeMillisEstimate: 0,
      works: 1,
      advanced: 0,
      needTime: 0,
      needYield: 0,
      saveState: 0,
      restoreState: 0,
      isEOF: 1
    }
  },
  command: {
    find: 'CitySearch',
    filter: { RequestId: '1232423' },
    '$db': 'test'
  },
  serverInfo: {
    host: 'LAPTOP-LH7H8EFV',
    port: 27017,
    version: '7.0.5',
    gitVersion: '7809d71e84e314b497f282ea8aa06d7ded3eb205'
  },
  serverParameters: {
    internalQueryFacetBufferSizeBytes: 104857600,
    internalQueryFacetMaxOutputDocSizeBytes: 104857600,
    internalLookupStageIntermediateDocumentMaxSizeBytes: 104857600,
    internalDocumentSourceGroupMaxMemoryBytes: 104857600,
    internalQueryMaxBlockingSortMemoryUsageBytes: 104857600,
    internalQueryProhibitBlockingMergeOnMongoS: 0,
    internalQueryMaxAddToSetBytes: 104857600,
    internalDocumentSourceSetWindowFieldsMaxMemoryBytes: 104857600,
    internalQueryFrameworkControl: 'trySbeRestricted'
  },
  ok: 1
}
```

how to improve this process?

Comment: how many records are returned in .net application?

Comment: 130, 2500-3000 milliseconds are all high for 600 documents searching. Probably your document size is a lot and it is losing time on converting the result to a list. You might start trying by FindOne and returning only the required fields instead of the whole document. Check aggregation pipeline.

Comment: @dododo >net application is returning 600 records

Comment: @CetinBasoz Yes, document size is very high

Comment: when you run the query in .net with `ToList()`, it returns all 600 records (ie all batches) where when you run it in Compas, it returns only first 20 records in the first batch